# How convert php soap client application into java

Tags: java, php, rest, erp, php-java-bridge

webERP Opensource

below is the PHP Client soap Client API. How to convert this PHP Client script into JAVA client script.

Client program contain 5 arguments.

```
<?php
        include 'xmlrpc/lib/xmlrpc.inc';

    include 'config.inc';

    echo '<a href="index.php">Home</a></BR>';
        $_POST['debtor'] = "ARGUMENT 1";
        $weberpuser = "ARGUMENT 2"; 
        $weberppassword = "ARGUMENT 3"; 
        $DebugLevel = 1;
        $ServerURL = "ARGUMENT 4";
    if (isset($_GET['debtorno'])) {
        $_POST['debtor']=$_GET['debtorno'];
        $_POST['submit']='set';
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo '<FORM METHOD="post" action=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '>Enter customer code';
        echo '<INPUT type="text" name="debtor"></BR><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Find Customer">';
        echo '</FORM>';
    } else {
        $debtorno = new xmlrpcval($_POST['debtor']);
        $user = new xmlrpcval($weberpuser);
        $password = new xmlrpcval($weberppassword);
        // weberp.xmlrpc_GetCustomer ARGUMENT 5 
        $msg = new xmlrpcmsg("weberp.xmlrpc_GetCustomer", array($debtorno, $user, $password));

        $client = new xmlrpc_client($ServerURL);
        $client->setDebug($DebugLevel);

        $response = $client->send($msg);
        $debtor = php_xmlrpc_decode($response->value());
        echo "<table border=1>";
        if (sizeof($debtor)<20) {
            echo 'oops, an error number '.$debtor[0].' has occurred';
        }
        foreach ($debtor as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_numeric($key)) {
                echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td><td>".$debtor[$key]."</td></tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

Please advise webERP rest service.

Comment: What Java Soap library you are going to use?

Comment: new to java. i have php, now i want to develop in java client, This java should work same like php client script

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm probably not completely following you. What exactly you want to do with Java? Do you want to recreate same thing in Java? Also do you just want to create a client in Java or also handle HTTP POST requests?

Comment: @jsalonen yes, i want to develop in java.

Comment: If you want to handle HTTP requests too then what kind of framework/library you are using?

Comment: first i want to do in core java

Comment: What do you mean with core Java? Java Servlets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54773/discussion-between-bharanikumar-and-jsalonen).

Comment: just i want to make sure, java can able to access my server api. so i want that in just simple java instead od jsp, servlet and etc

Comment: I cannot help you if you go offline

Comment: i am online. can please update

Comment: Check the follow up from chat

Comment: Hi @Bharanikumar, Did you got the solution. if yes then please suggest me i am having same problem.